# How can I prove, using a delta-epsilon argument that the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ of $\sqrt x$ is $0$?

Tags: calculus

I was only taught how to do proofs for polynomials and have tried many times without avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put $0\leq{x}<\delta< \epsilon^2$ then $\vert \sqrt{x}-0\vert<\epsilon$

Comment: not if $x<0$, only the one sided limit is defined.

Comment: you are quite right, thank you.